# Javascript file import with query param fails in PHP Standalone Server with PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, php, html, phantomjs, codeception

The problem occurs on my test environment. Locally everything works fine(apache server). On test environment I have this stack: PHP 5.6, PHP Standalone Server, Codeception and PhantomJS 1.9.7.

In affected HTML Template I have following JavaScript import tag:

```
<script defer src="/js/my_file.js?v=0"></script>
```

Because of `?v=0` query param, this resource(and every with query param) can't be find.

In logs I can see that file was requested, but somehow it's not returned by server:

```
::1 2016-11-08T16:06:01+01:00 "GET /js/my_file.js?v=0 HTTP/1.1" http://localhost:8080/ Mozilla/5.0 (Unknown; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/534.34 (KHTML, like Gecko) PhantomJS/1.9.7 Safari/534.34`
```

Browser returns `404 - not found error`.

I also tried to remove `defer` from `src` tag, but it didn't change anything.

Comment: Sounds like a server/CDN problem.

Comment: @Vaviloff, if I would know how to resolve that problem :P